# How to Add filter Backends in when you override list?

Tags: django-rest-framework

If I override list, filter backends is not working. How to apply my filter if I override list definition?

```
class CircuitViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Circuit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CircuitSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = CircuitFilter

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Circuit.objects.all()
        serializer = CircuitSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I wonder if you found a solution for this problem. Would appreciate if you could share it. Thx!

Comment: @Chris I added my answer below. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 6):

```
class CircuitViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Circuit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CircuitSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = CircuitFilter

    def list(self, request):
        # with filter
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        # pagination
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: You saved me tons of time!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before. In my example, I just removed `filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)` part and filtering started to work.